# (Obj-C) Decode JSON with accents in Dictionary from NSHTTPURLResponse (allHeaderFields)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary

I'm receiving header fields from NSHTTPURLResponse as a NSDictionary in this way:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response]);
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
```

but in values of this dictionary has accents and when I try to show as Alert, appears symbols instead of letters with accents. I used this way:

```
NSError * err;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:[response allHeaderFields] options:0 error:&err];

id rootObject = [NSJSONSerialization
                   JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                              options:0
                                error:&error];

NSDictionary *rootDictionary = rootObject;
```

In my headers, I receive this:

```
headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Length" = 30;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 10 Dec 2015 15:47:07 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "xxxxx";
    "X-Error" = "Par\U00c3\U00a1metros faltantes";
    "X-Powered-By" = "xxxxxx";
}
```

And I show in alert THE X-Error value:

```
NSString *description = [rootDictionary objectForKey:@"X-Error"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title of my alert" message:description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [alert show];
```

This is my result:

> ParÃ¡metros faltantes

This is my Dictionary log in Xcode (NSLog):

```
{
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Language" = en;
    "Content-Length" = 30;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 10 Dec 2015 16:13:00 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "xxxxxx";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "xxxxxx";
    "X-Error" = "Par\U00c3\U00a1metros faltantes";
    "X-Powered-By" = "xxxxx";
}
```

Anyone have another solution?

Comment: You need to update your question with more details about the data you have and the results you are seeing.

Comment: Ready @rmaddy, I updated

Comment: Update your question with the `NSLog` output of `rootDictionary` and show the code used to get from `rootDictionary` to the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I could doing this:

```
NSDictionary *headerField = [response allHeaderFields];
NSString *description = [headerField valueForKey:@"X-Error"];
NSString *correctString = [NSString stringWithCString:[description cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The important element is **cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding**. And correctString give me accents correctly!